# Using PHP as "redirect" for Arduino

Tags: php, arduino

I've created an Arduino Ethernet sketch, such that on a button push, it requests a URL (http://myserver.lan/sensors/garage.php). My thought was that I could then use this [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) script to pull a separate URL that I can update without having to reflash the Arduino. This separate URL drives certain home automation events.

I tried the following in `garage.php`:

```
<?php
    $homepage = file_get_contents('http://myserver.lan/test/');
?>
```

This works for my browser, but not for the Arduino board. The logs for the two are as follows:

Arduino:

```
192.168.2.50 - - [21/Mar/2013:13:43:58 -0400] "GET /sensors/garage.php HTTP/1.1" 400 515 "-" "-"
```

Safari:

```
192.168.2.3 - - [21/Mar/2013:13:43:28 -0400] "GET /test/ HTTP/1.0" 200 2235 "-" "-"
192.168.2.65 - - [21/Mar/2013:13:43:28 -0400] "GET /sensors/garage.php HTTP/1.1" 200 293 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_3) AppleWebKit/536.28.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0.3 Safari/536.28.10"
```

For completeness, here is the code sample from my Arduino sketch:

```
EthernetClient client;
if (client.connect(rackserver, 80)) {
    client.println("GET /sensors/garage.php HTTP/1.1");
}
client.stop();
```

How can I fix the PHP script? I'm hoping to accomplish this without reflashing my Arduino.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how the log of the Arduino request shows that the server responded with a response code of `400` (bad request). Your Arduino code is not sending a valid HTTP request, for two reasons:

1. A valid HTTP request terminates with an empty line.
2. You specified HTTP version 1.1, which mandates that a request contains a `Host:` header.

Try this instead:

```
EthernetClient client;
if (client.connect(rackserver, 80)) {
  client.println("GET /sensors/garage.php HTTP/1.0");
  client.println();
}
client.stop();
```